# Linguijs and FilePond format conflict. Can't use { char properly

Tags: filepond, linguijs

In the [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-validate-size/) we should localize text with the use of attributes.
For example `labelMaxFileSize="Maximum file size is {filesize}"`.
In the project we are using [js-lingui](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui).
So actual translation would look like this:

```
labelMaxFileSize: i18n._(t`Maximum file size is {filesize}`),
```

Problem: both FilePond and lingui use `{}` chars to mark variables. And this causing problem.
How it may be fixed?

Comment: Looked around the lingui docs, but couldn't find it. I would expect there should some way to tell lingui that your sentence contains literal characters. Maybe escaping them works? ```labelMaxFileSize: i18n._(t`Maximum file size is \{filesize\}`),```

Comment: @rik sure, I have tried that. I don't get error if I do it like that: ```i18n._(t`Maximum file size is \\{filesize\\}`)```. But it actually doesn't translate anything that way also.

Comment: Error text: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filesize' of undefined` — it came from /node_modules/@lingui/core/cjs/core.development.js:134
I suppose that lingui think that filesize is lingui variable and expect filesize value should be passed. But it's should be passed by filephond.

Comment: I would think this isn't the first time that someone tries to translate something that has a `{foo}` block in it.

Comment: @rik same here, but I can't google the solution yet. There is two possible way to solve this: 1. somehow escape {} — failing at the moment. 2. setup symbols FilePond using to mark variable. Look like there is no way to do it at the moment.

Comment: Actually I have found pretty nit solution, but still far from ideal:
```javascript
function printf(fmt, ...args) {
  return fmt.split('%%').reduce((aggregate, chunk, i) => aggregate + chunk + (args[i] || ''), '');
}
// …
labelMaxTotalFileSize: printf(i18n._(t`Maximum total file size is %% `), '{filesize}'),
```